# How to update a sesame triplestore using a custom HTML form?

Tags: rdf, sparql, semantic-web, sesame, triplestore

I want to create a form (with php or python code) where people will fill in data and automatically update my triples in the Sesame triplestore, I read that SPARQL 1.1 does update to the triplestore but I dont know how to make an html form interact with a triplestore. Any guide??

Comment: Sesame has a REST API that you can talk to from pretty much any web development platform, and a Java API if you happen to work in JSP, JSF, or any other Java-related web platform. I suggest you do some reading on how to talk to a REST service, and have a look at Sesame's API documentation. If you get stuck, feel free to ask a more specific question here!

Answer (score 1):

As guide you should read SPARQL 1.1 [Update Language](http://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-update/) and [Protocol for RDF](http://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-protocol/).

But, in case it may help and you prefer an example rather than a specification, you can based on the [Apache Marmotta's SPARQL Update form](https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf?p=marmotta.git;a=blob;f=platform/marmotta-sparql/src/main/resources/web/admin/update.html;h=691ad6678d36db1b24f5984b1792fb866fc0981d;hb=HEAD) (source code under Apache License 2.0).

It's only based on HTML+JS. And, although Marmotta in build on top of Sesame, this is irrelevant, since the form is build to work over any SPARQL 1.1 Update compatible implementation.